# Need help using ldap to convert ${CCNetModifyingUsers} to list of email addresses

Tags: ldap, cruisecontrol.net

I am trying to configure an email publisher to send email upon failure to the user[s] that contributed to a failed build. If that's not possible because it's a list, then perhaps I can configure tasks that do a forced build, in which case I could use ${CCNetUser}.

This is my attempt at configuring it because I could not find anything helpful other than the LDAP Email Converter page in the cc.net documentation.

```
<converters>  
    <ldapConverter domainName="xxxxxx.com" />   
    <!--not sure if needed: ldapLogOnUser="LdapQuery" ldapLogOnPassword="****"-->   
</converters>  
<users>  
    <cb:define userEmail="${CCNetModifyingUsers}" />  
    <user name="buildmaster" group="buildmaster" address="$(userEmail)" />  
</users>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out.
The solution, which was not clear from the documentation, was to use this type of user node:

```
<user name="${CCNetFailureUsers}" group="failure" address="" />
```

The user name uses the dynamic variable that resolves to the list of users that contributed to the failed build, the group defines notification for Failed builds (and exceptions in my configuration) and a blank address is what triggers the ldapConverter.